# Is it possible to transfer authorized Windows's user credentials to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, client-object-model

I have a console application that connects to the SharePoint and works with lists (I'm using SharePoint Client model). Code that connects with SharePoint is:

```
SPCli.ClientContext _clientContext = new SPCli.ClientContext("server-url");
_clientContext.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
SPCli.Web web = _clientContext.Web;
```

As you can see, the program has access to SharePoint, the user must manually enter his login data. For example, user's login data in Windows and SharePoint are the same. It is possible to transfer authorized Windows's user credentials to SharePoint? 
I tried to look for ways to do it at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.aspx, but I  didn't find the solution.

Comment: Are you need to avoid manually login ?

Comment: Yes, I want to try the automatic authorization without manually input

Comment: Are you tried to use 

    clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

Comment: Yes, but i got an error "401 unauthenticated error"

Comment: The windows user should have the sufficient permission on the site , make sure the windows login user have access to SharePoint site

Comment: Thank you very much, M.Qassas, it works now. I did not think that the transfer of Windows login сredentials to SharePoint can look so easy.

Comment: Dear @AndryNuzha, Great to hear that so I moved this solution to answer section to be useful for others. please click on true symbol beside my answer to set it as the answer and close this question. Thanks for your cooperation and appreciating my time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
_clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

And make sure that the current windows login user that run your application have the sufficient permission to access the SharePoint site and the resource (`like List or Library ...etc`) that you need to do action on it within site.